# How can I delete my account/profile from asp.net forums?

Tags: account-management, forums

I've created a profile to [asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net?) which has my full name as username and I don't want it to be displayed on my every posts. If I can change username then good, otherwise I want to delete that profile.

Answer (score 1):

Contact their support.

Comment: Can you please provide any link about where can I contact them?

Comment: There's a [Contact](http://www.asp.net/feedback/) link at the foot of the page - http://www.asp.net/feedback/

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your profile name on [this page](https://forums.asp.net/user/editprofile.aspx)  It is linked at the top right of the forum pages when you are signed in.

Comment: :( There isn't any input provided for profile name change.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change your username nor can you directly deactivate your account according to this:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1933703.aspx

I tried the contact link at the bottom of the page takes you to a maze worthy of phone-tree envy.

I was only able to deactivate my account by posting a message in the "Feedback on this website" forum: http://forums.asp.net/188.aspx/1?Feedback+on+this+website and wait for a moderator to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit an ASP.NET site operations help support ticket from the [Contact Us page](http://www.asp.net/contact-us).